# behavior of function at infinite

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals

Yesterday I was looking for problems about improper integrals. In a book by B.P. Demidovich I found this nice problem:
Suppose $f$ is a $C^1(R)$ function with bounded derivative (i.e. $|f'(x)|<M$ for all $x\in R$). Prove that if 
$$
\int_0^\infty |f(x)|\,dx < \infty,
$$
then $\displaystyle{\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} f(x) =0}$.

We can prove this noting that the integral $\int_0^\infty f(x) \, f'(x) \,dx$ is convergent. $\square$

I wonder if we can replace the hypothesis about the absolute convergence of the integral by symply convergence:
$$
\lim_{M\rightarrow \infty} \int_0^M f(x)\,dx \mbox{ exists.} 
$$
I suspect the result is still true but I did not realize how to prove it. I think que can not use now that  $\int_0^\infty f(x) \, f'(x) \,dx$ is convergent. 
I appreciate any suggestions you can give me.

Comment: $|f'(x)|<M$ is still a condition. Sorry for not clarifying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $|f'(x)| \leq M$ then by the mean value inequality we have the following estimate
\begin{align}
|f(x) - f(y)| = |f'(\xi)(x-y)| \leq M|x-y| 
\end{align}
for all $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$. Hence it follows $f$ is uniformly continuous.

Suppose the limit of $f$ as $x \rightarrow \infty$ is not zero. In a more precise manner, there is an $\epsilon>0$ where for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ there exists $x_n>n$ such that $|f(x_n)|>\epsilon$. Moreover, by uniform continuity of $f$ on $\mathbb{R}$, there exists $\delta>0$ such that for all $|x_n-y|<\delta$ we have that $|f(x_n)-f(y)|<\epsilon/2$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ which means
\begin{align}
\epsilon<|f(x_n)|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}+|f(y)|  \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ |f(y)| >\frac{\epsilon}{2}
\end{align}
whenever $|x_n-y|<\delta$ for all $n$. (Heuristically, this means that we could fit infinitely many boxes of volume $\delta* \epsilon/2$ under the curve of $f$.)

Next, consider the sequence  $y_n$ defines as follows
\begin{align}
y_1 = x_1 -\delta, y_2 = x_1 + \delta, y_3 = x_2-\delta, \ldots
\end{align}
then it follows either 
\begin{align}
\int^{y_{2k}}_0 f(x) \ dx -\int^{y_{2k-1}}_0 f(x)\ dx = \int^{y_{2k}}_{y_{2k-1}} f(x)\ dx> \frac{\epsilon}{2}\delta  \ \ \text{ or } \ \  \ \int^{y_{2k}}_{y_{2k-1}} f(x)\ dx< -\frac{\epsilon}{2}\delta 
\end{align}
which means 
\begin{align}
\int^{y_n}_0 f(x)\ dx 
\end{align}
doesn't form a Cauchy sequence, i.e. the limit doesn't exists, a contradiction since the limit does exists.